remove parent menu link in WordPress (remove href attribut)
I created parent menus by indicating as URL #, but this creates a bug to open the submenus in mobile version with the touch because the url # refreshes the page.
To solve this problem I removed the url # from the parent menus, but this to create an SEO error in google speed because href attributes, the links cannot be explored.
How to remove the attribute from the parent menus of wordpress?
Thx for help
Hi
I created parent menus by indicating as URL #, but this creates a bug to open the submenus in mobile version with the touch because the url # refreshes the page.
To solve this problem I removed the url # from the parent menus, but this to create an SEO error in google speed because href attributes, the links cannot be explored.
How to remove the attribute from the parent menus of wordpress?
Thx for help
thx
